# Unstable maven-dependency-plugin (specific folder is not always generated/included in .jar file)

Tags: angular, maven, jenkins, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

We currently use a [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) pipeline for an [Angular 7](https://angular.io/) and [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) project, in which, among other things, the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) is in use.

Unfortunately, we have the problem that the **"coverage"** folder, which is generated automatically after the unit tests pass successfully (by using [jasmine/karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/configuration-file.html)), does not always end up in the final **.jar** file.

I have to repeat the process again and again, so that the folder eventually ends up in the .jar file. Really happens only now and then, if I'm lucky ^^. The folder is definitely always generated and ends up in both the **"dist"** and the **"target"** folder. It is really missing only in the **.jar** file or better said is not always stored in it.

Is this problem known or is there a better solution that I can put into my **pom.xml**?

Here is the current state of my **pom.xml**. I also post the part with the maven-resources-plugin, if that should help.

```
 ...
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies-to-target</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>dist</classifier>
          <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
          <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
          <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
          <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>dist</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <includes>
                <include>**</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
      <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The remaining plugins, which are in use, I always use in the latest and most stable version.

I hope someone can help me, so that the builds in the Jekins pipeline are stable and I can rely on it.